# RxJs Subject error - cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subject-observer

In my service method that returns `Observable` I'm trying to notify the component via `Subject` that an action completed.

```
completed: Subject<boolean>

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  loadItems(): Observable<FrontItemDto[]> {
    return this.http.get ( `${ServiceSettings.ApiUrl}/front` )
      .map ( res => {
        res.json ();
        if ( res.json () ) {
          this.completed.next ( true );
        }
      } )
      .catch ( (error: any) => Observable.throw ( error.json ().error || 'Server error' ) );
  }
```

This is how the component is listening to `Subject`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getItems();
    this.sub = this.dataService.completed.subscribe(completed => {
      if (completed) {
        this.show = false;
      }
      });
  }
```

But I'm getting an error saying that Subject (completed) is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have not initialized `completed` Subject correctly

```
completed = new Subject<boolean>(); //it should have parenthesis at the end
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/isLZ6lrkroFdwDBhvQWX) by @Ompurdy

Comment: I was about to say this: upvotes for you :) [plunker demonstrating it](https://plnkr.co/edit/isLZ6lrkroFdwDBhvQWX) for anyone who wants to test

Comment: Thanks mate, I added it in the answer :)