# How to bind service variable with component Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have an variable: `public tick:number;` in service.

The service has injection of another service Timer. It is launched like as:

```
class Service {

constructor(public timer: TimerService)

}

public sendSmsExect(){
   // Main sending
}

public sendSms(){

    this.timer.run().subscribe((tick => { if(tick == 30) { sendSmsExect(); } }));

}

}
```

**Component:**

```
class MyComponent {

    public constructor(public service Service){}

    public sendSms(){
       this.service.sendSms();
    }

}
```

Problem: I need to get access to tick varaible in template:

```
{{tick}}
```

Do I really think that I need to subscribe to `tick` also in component and define the same variable `tick`:

```
public sendSms(){
   this.service.sendSms().subscribe((tick) => this.tick = tick );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider sharing `tick` variable value from service using `Subject` observable. By making it observable you don't need to subscribe it an unwrap the value of tick from it. You need to use `| async` pipe on HTML, which will take care of unwrapping value of `tick` and displaying it on HTML.

**Code**

```
//don't miss below import
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

class MyService {
  tick: Subject < number > ();
  constructor(public timer: TimerService) {}

  sendSmsExect() {
    // Main sending
  }
  tickObservable() {
    return this.tick.asObservable();
  }

  public sendSms() {
    this.timer.run().subscribe(tick => {
      this.tick.next(tick);
      if (tick == 30) {
        sendSmsExect();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Component

```
//don't miss below import
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

class MyComponent {
    tick: Observable<number>();
    public constructor(public service: MyService ){}

    sendSms(){
       this.service.sendSms();
    }
    ngOnInit(){
       this.tick = this.service.tickObservable();
    }
}
```

**Html**

```
{{tick | async}}
```

Comment: @Daniel please refer to [this article](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services), there are many SO threads which you may find helpful :)

Comment: @Daniel about your solution, I'm still wondering, how `tick` value got available inside your component. Though the suggested way is preferred..

Comment: Here I get syntax error: `tick: Subject < number > ();`

Comment: Also where did you start: `this.timer.run()`?

Comment: And another error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'asObservable' of undefined
    at SmsService.tickObservable`

Comment: @Daniel did you imported `Subject `?

Comment: Yes, now problem in this: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'asObservable' of undefined
    at SmsService.tickObservable`

Comment: @Daniel `private tick: Subject <number>;` should be `private tick: Subject <number>();`, Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45259268/2435473) to know why it wasn't working?'